# What happens when you delete a Clustered index and Non Clustered Index once created

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2014, clustered-index, nonclustered-index

What happens when we dropped a Cluster index and Non Clustered Index once they are created?

What will happen to the data at the leaf level according to Clustered Index ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From MSDN:

> When a clustered index is dropped, the data rows that were stored in
>   the leaf level of the clustered index are stored in an unordered table
>   (heap). Dropping a clustered index can take time because in addition
>   to dropping the clustered index, all nonclustered indexes on the table
>   must be rebuilt to replace the clustered index keys with row pointers
>   to the heap. When you drop all indexes on a table, drop the
>   nonclustered indexes first and the clustered index last. That way, no
>   indexes have to be rebuilt.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190691(v=sql.105).aspx

As for the nonclustered index drops, they aren't DELETING any data, it's a metadata operation and the index pages are simply deallocated. Think about TRUNCATE versus DELETE, TRUNCATE just deallocates the pages and you're done.  Dropping a nonclustered index is very similar, hence why dropping one is lightning fast when you do it (unless you are blocked).